# Concat two columns in where clause in laravel mongodb to search

Tags: laravel, mongodb

Here is my code

```
$users = User::where('f_name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
    ->orWhere('l_name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
    ->orWhere('state', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
    ->orWhere('city', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
    ->orWhere('country', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
    ->orWhere('university', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
    ->orWhere('company', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
    ->orWhere('degree', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
    ->orWhere('dream_job', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
    ->with('roles')
    ->WhereHas("roles", function ($q) {
        $q->where('name', '<>', ADMIN_ROLE)->where('name', '<>', SUPERADMIN_ROLE);
    })
    ->get();
```

I want to concat the `f_name` and `l_name` columns so that I can search with full name

Answer (score -2):

**Try to do this using concat function:**

```
User::whereRaw("concat(f_name, ' ', l_name) LIKE '%?%'", [$search])
```

Thanks

Comment: $or/$and/$nor entries need to be full objects it return this error

Comment: if you have solved your problem, describe the solution in a new answer and mark it as accepted. This helps other people with the same error.

Comment: Placeholders should not be quoted, so this query will not work as expected. The proper way to bind parameters is shown in the question above.